# Center crop the feature image

Tags: posts, images, post-thumbnails

[image]

Could someone help me to perfectly center crop the thumbnails(feature image) as showing in the picture

Comment: Thumbnails are cropped from the center by default. I don't understand what your issue is exactly. Are the images in your screenshot not centered?

Comment: exactly images not centered how to achieve that

Comment: How are they not centered? What are the originals?

Comment: Content of the image is not properly centered